# Can you gift a weapon multiple times?

Tags: diablo-iii

Say I would gift a weapon to add a socket, then roll the socket into something else and then gift it again. Are there restrictions as to how often you can gift a weapon? Has anyone been lucky enough to get to test this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't roll the socket from Ramalammadingdong's Gift, so you can't add a second one.

Comment: That's what I call it too